# Alternatives to appearance proxy for Table Cells' UILabel setFont

Tags: uitableview, ios5, fonts, uilabel, appearance

I'm loving being able to use an appearance proxy in my iOS5 app to customise the NavigationController UI elements system-wide, however:

I have a lot of nested tables in my app, of which I'd love to be able to change the font across all table cells. They are mainly statically created. I've put some cell generation inside of a class, being read from an array, but the main issue lies with a large contents section I've tabled in Interface Builder. IB doesn't seem to have the option for mass-font setting.

**I was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to set all the UITableCell fonts in one go?**

Perhaps something like:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times" size:17.00];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to narrow down which UIViews you'd like to set the appearance for.

In your example, try:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] 
          setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times" size:17.00]];
```

Comment: Thanks very much - a good way to concentrate on specific elements - I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: After a long and heated discussion with a colleague he correctly informed me that UILabel (amongst other classes which *respond* to `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`) does not conform to the `UIAppearance` protocol, so even though this may *work* it is undocumented and therefore not to be relied upon).

Comment: @NSTJ `UILabel` inherits from `UIView`, which conforms to `UIAppearance`; ergo `UILabel` *does* conform to `UIAppearance`~~, and this method may be relied upon~~.

Comment: ...But none of the methods have the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` property, so maybe not so reliable/supported after all.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, no. It is not valid to use UIAppearance to style a UILabel. See [my self-answered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839044/how-do-i-apply-uiappearance-proxy-properties-to-uilabel). It kinda works, but it's not valid, for the reasons outlined over there.